# window.resize using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my code last  `420` condition is not executed when I resize the window width 420 at this width 768 is execute what might be the problem can anyone suggest me. I'm trying to add CSS on window resize.

```js
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  var win = $(window); //this = window
  if (win.width() > 425) { 
    $('.box').css('background-color','green');
  }
  if (win.width() > 768) { 
    $('.box').css('background-color','blue');
  }
  if (win.width() > 1024) { 
    $('.box').css('background-color','red');
  }

});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: What '420 condition'? I only see `425`, `768` and `1024`. Also note that amending styling based on window size should be done in CSS, not JS

Comment: instead of jQuery use css media query

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i want to add some js code on window resize without refresh the page

Comment: css media queries do not require page to be reloaded.

Comment: @SumitPatel I want to change an svg cubic beizer in html as they are pixel based. How can i do that using media queries??

Comment: @LelioFaieta I want to change the SVG Cubic Bezier curve in HTML. As you know we can't do that using media queries.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan read my latest comment.

Comment: You would need to use JS for that, however you would have gotten more useful answers if you'd added a more accurate example of the code, and explanation of your goal, to the question in the first instance

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The code was just to explain that the js was not working correctly. the project I'm working on has NDA I cant post that here. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to archive it using CSS Media queries but if you really need then try this.

```
 $(window).on('resize', function(){
  var win = $(window); //this = window
  if (win.width() >= 425 && win.width() < 768) { 
    $('.box').css('background-color','green');
  }
  else if  (win.width() >= 768 && win.width() < 1024) { 
    $('.box').css('background-color','blue');
  }
  else if  (win.width() >= 1024) { 
    $('.box').css('background-color','red');
  }
  else{
   //write here it will be execute when size is less then 425
  }

});
```

Comment: both red and blue are working fine but the green is not working can you have a look

Comment: Its working absolutely fine now. as i was resizing the inspect window not the browser window.

Answer (score 4):

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 425px) {
    .box {
        background-color: green;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .box {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .box {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

**JS:**

Also if you would like to use JS (jQuery) and apply this logic after window.ready you can use the next code (in a few words trigger resize event):
https://jsfiddle.net/dqm634ro/

Comment: On window resize without refresh the page.